# MDX equivalent of SQL Query

Tags: mysql, mdx, mondrian

What will be MDX query equivalent to:

```
select * from tableName where somecount > num1 and somecount < num2?
```

`somecount` is a dimension in my case (not a dimension).

As far as I have understood, `WHERE` Clause in MDX Queries doesn't support less than or greater than operation. `somecount` in my case is `Timestamp`. Since I want to aggregate data on parameters passed by user (can be aggregated yesterday, last 7 days, last 15 days, last month etc). So, precomputing the timestamp and storing it as Year-Month-Day-Time won't help.

Comment: To achieve "somecount > num1" you need to read up on the MDX Filter() function.

Answer (score 1):

There is a common mistake mixing SQL and MDX due to the similar syntax. but MDX is not like SQL.

I'd advise going through this [Gentle MDX Tutorial](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html) to get a better understanding.

```
Select *
```

There is no equivalent of * in MDX you have to specify your axes by putting your dimensions. You can use [Measures].members to select a list of measures for example.

```
.. where somecount > num1 and somecount < num2?
```

The translation for this is using [MDX subselects](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/SubQueries.html), strange but [MDX where clause](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Where%20Clause.html) is something different. It's more like :

```
Select [Measures].members on 0
from (
   select {All the members that match your filter} from [MyCube] 
)
```

There is a couple of ways getting a list of members, check the list of [MDX functions available](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/functions.html) to get an idea of all that is possible.

Good luck with your first steps in MDX.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MEMBERS ON ROWS  FROM (SELECT Filter(filter) ON COLUMNS  FROM [FACT_TABLE])
```

Filter should be something like this

```
Filter([TIME].[YEAR].[YEAR].AllMembers, (
[TIME].[YEAR].CurrentMember.member_caption>="2009" AND 
[TIME].YEAR].CurrentMember.member_caption<="2012" ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Measures.members ON ROWS,
      Dimension.members ON Columns
  FROM Cube
 WHERE somecount.value > num1 
   AND somecount.value < num2
```